# Why is XRDP not working? Ive followed numerous tutorials and I still cant connect. (New to Ubuntu)

Tags: 20.04, xfce, xrdp

When trying to connect to my Ubuntu 20.04 system from my windows 10 laptop, it says it cannot connect. Ive tried using xfce4 and others but it says the same thing. I have allowed 3389 through the firewall and it still doesnt allow me to connect. How can I fix it?

edit- not using xfce4. Reinstalled xrdp and still nothing.

Comment: How are you trying to connect on the Windows side? Output of `/etc/init.d/xrdp status`  and `sudo apt search xrdp`?

Comment: I found the problem. I was using an older router and the way it was configured wasnt allowing it to see other devices.